# Retrieve Values from Two Tags Regardless of their Position

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I have an XML like below where I want to get the values of the tags customerid and participationtype regardless of their position inside ASObject.

I have tried to write regex like below which is not working when the order of the tags is not matched.

```
<customerid tagClass="double">(.*)</customerid>([^^]*?)<participationtype tagClass="String">(clmt|insrd)</participationtype>
```

XML:

```
<ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">
  <customertype tagClass="String">prsn</customertype>
  <linkednoteindicator tagClass="boolean">false</linkednoteindicator>
  <new tagClass="boolean">true</new>
  <customerid tagClass="double">3209053.0</customerid>
  <participationtype tagClass="String">clmt</participationtype>
  <updated tagClass="boolean">true</updated>
  <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
  <blockexist tagClass="boolean">false</blockexist>
  <participationid tagClass="double">2664273.0</participationid>
  <customername tagClass="String">MELISSA M. CORNWELL</customername>
  <customerphonenumber tagClass="String">3303660069</customerphonenumber>
  <effectivedate tagClass="Date">1997-03-02 19:00:00.0 EST</effectivedate>
</ASObject>
```

Comment: Why are people obsessed with parsing XML with regex? [Bad, bad idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649) Use an XML parser, that's what they're for.

Comment: My tool allows only XPath or regex to parse the XMLs, no other way. It is becoming hard to retrieved two values with XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general advice is to use XPath instead of use regex to parse xml. However, if you do want to do it in regex, you can use this pattern:

```
(?s)\A(?=.*<customerid[^>]*>([^<>]*)</customerid>)(?=.*<participationtype[^>]*>([^<>]*)</participationtype>)
```

In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mU7lT6/3)**, look at the **right pane** to see the captures.

We retrieve the matches from Groups 1 and 2 like so:

```
if ($yourString =~ m!(?s)\A(?=.*<customerid[^>]*>([^<>]*)</customerid>)(?=.*<participationtype[^>]*>([^<>]*)</participationtype>)!) {
    $customerid = $1;
    $participationtype = $1;
}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `\A` asserts our position at the beginning of the string
- The lookahead `(?=.*<customerid[^>]*>([^<>]*)</customerid>)` captures the id to Group 1
- The lookahead `(?=.*<participationtype[^>]*>([^<>]*)</participationtype>)` captures the type to Group 2